# Data usage by an Ajax Response Text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am actually getting an Ajax Response Text from a PHP Server. Suppose the response text comprises of 20 characters.

(e.g. echo "asdhfgyd dhrjtjsjtjr";)

This equals roughly (20/1024) KB.

I'm using a mobile web application to get this reponse text using standard Ajax XMLHttpRequest. However when i measure the data usage by the mobile app due to only that one single ajax response text, it uses nearly 3 KB. This is what i'm not understanding, what is causing this additional data usage, can you please help me out on this.

Additionaly: I confirm that this is the only part of the app that makes internet usage, the others are offline features.

Comment: What is the response type? If it is HTML or text you are likely getting back headers and other information.

Answer (score 2):

The data you see in the response text is only the body of the response. The other bytes will most likely have been taken up by the headers.

For example here is a response I would expect to receive when calling an API:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?XFxwc2ZcSG9tZVxEb2N1bWVudHNcR2l0SHViXFNvdXJjZVxDaGVyaXNoQXF00XJpc2guQXBpXGFwaVxjaGlsZFxsaXN0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2015 09:02:35 GMT
Content-Length: 577

[{"result":"FooBar"}]
```

Comment: Are there other ways such that less overhead information is transmitted. I mean using for example JSON/XML with AJAX, will it use less data?

Comment: I'm afraid not. All information sent via HTTP requires headers to be sent.